# azure storage blob upload subdirectories recursive not working

Tags: azure, storage, command-line-interface, azure-storage

```
        filter="$dir_to_upload*"
        for file in $filter; do
            azure storage blob upload -q $file $container_name $(basename $file)
        done
```

I want to write a shell script that upload subdirectories and files using azure cli but everytime the script encounter a directory, it just skip and throws an error `"error:   storage blob upload command failed"` saying this is not a file.  How to I upload a subdirectories and files recursively similar to azcopy /S.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call "azure storage blob upload" when the $file is actually a directory. Actually, in order to enumerate files (except directories) under a directory recursively, you can simply call "find $dir_to_upload -type f" to do so.

Comment: I tried this and is very slow when uploading file by file.  Tendency I get a timeout session from Azure.  Is there other way to do it similar to AzCopy?

Comment: You can refer to the answer of Yang Xia.

Answer (score 1):

Azure CLI itself doesn't upload files in a directory recursively and in parallel. While using "**find $dir_to_upload -type f**", you may also want to try the [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-dir-processor) and check whether it can help. But please be careful about the error handling when operations failed or be interrupted.